# Nice way to turn a dict into a TypedDict?

Tags: python-3.x, types, mypy

**Note**: since this answer keeps getting upvoted - while there are still use cases for `TypedDict`, I'd consider using a `dataclass` instead today.

---

I want to have a nice (`mypy --strict` and pythonic) way to turn an untyped `dict` (from `json.loads()`) into a `TypedDict`. My current approach looks like this:

```
class BackupData(TypedDict, total=False):
    archive_name: str
    archive_size: int
    transfer_size: int
    transfer_time: float
    error: str


def to_backup_data(data: Mapping[str, Any]) -> BackupData:
    result = BackupData()
    if 'archive_name' in data:
        result['archive_name'] = str(data['archive_name'])
    if 'archive_size' in data:
        result['archive_size'] = int(data['archive_size'])
    if 'transfer_size' in data:
        result['transfer_size'] = int(data['transfer_size'])
    if 'transfer_time' in data:
        result['transfer_time'] = int(data['transfer_time'])
    if 'error' in data:
        result['error'] = str(data['error'])
    return result
```

i.e I have a `TypedDict` with optional keys and want a `TypedDict` instance.

The code above is redundant and non-functional (in terms of functional programming) because I have to write names four times, types twice and `result` has to be mutable.
Sadly `TypedDict` can't have methods otherwise I could write s.th. like

```
backup_data = BackupData.from(json.loads({...}))
```

Is there something I'm missing regarding `TypeDict`? Can this be written in a nice, non-redundant way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a TypedDict, all information is stored in the `__annotations__` field.

For your example:

```
BackupData.__annotations__
```

returns:

```
{'archive_name': <class 'str'>, 'archive_size': <class 'int'>, 'transfer_size': <class 'int'>, 'transfer_time': <class 'float'>, 'error': <class 'str'>}
```

Now we can use that dictionary to iterate over the data and use the values for type casting:

```
def to_backup_data(data: Mapping[str, Any]) -> BackupData:
    result = BackupData()
    for key, key_type in BackupData.__annotations__.items():
        if key not in data:
            raise ValueError(f"Key: {key} is not available in data.")
        result[key] = key_type(data[key])
    return result
```

Note that I throw an error when the data is not available, this can be changed at your discretion.

With the following test code:

```
data = dict(
        archive_name="my archive",
        archive_size="50",
        transfer_size="100",
        transfer_time="2.3",
        error=None,
)

for key, value in result.items():
    print(f"Key: {key.ljust(15)}, type: {str(type(value)).ljust(15)}, value: {value!r}")
```

The result will be:

```
Key: archive_name   , type: <class 'str'>  , value: 'my archive'
Key: archive_size   , type: <class 'int'>  , value: 50
Key: transfer_size  , type: <class 'int'>  , value: 100
Key: transfer_time  , type: <class 'float'>, value: 2.3
Key: error          , type: <class 'str'>  , value: 'None'
```

Comment: While I love this approach, it could lead to some unexpected behavior as-is. If, for example, in the source dict, `archive_name` was `None`, the resulting data would appear as `"None"`, as `str(None) -> "None"`.

Comment: Hi Joe, that is true, that is why I provided an example with `error=None`, which results indeed in the string `'None'`. Unfortunately I didn't give more attention to it while typing the answer. In the case you would like to accept `None` as possible answer, the typing should be `Optional[str]`, for which the above solution wouldn't work.

Comment: I think your answer is a great starting point, and more behavior should probably added as appropriate for whatever app it's in. I just wanted to warn future googlers!